# Resolution of javascript resources/libraries/dependencies by the Webstorm IDE

Tags: webstorm

I am new to the Webstorm IDE and would like to know how this IDE resolves javascript dependencies/libraries.

For instance say I have a folder/project with **a number of vendor dependencies** as well as **my own *.js files**.

1. How Webstorm is going to **find those vendor dependencies** files?
2. How is Webstorm going to **know in which order to load those found dependencies**?
3. Can I **use some dependency management tool** such as Bower together with Webstorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default WebStorm uses a global scope for resolving dependencies inside a given .js file. It means that all .js files (external dependencies/your own files) located in the project root will be used in one single global resolve scope by default.

You can create a library using "Settings | JavaScrit | Libraries" and associate it with a custom scope. That allows to exclude the created library from global scope - it will be used in resolve for the specified scope only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How about the order of libraries with custom scopes? Also, can you please kindly provide a link to relevant documentation?

Comment: Sorry. Here is the link http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/javascript-usage-scope.html .
No, there is no particular order of libraries with custom scopes.

Comment: Thanks for the link. About the order of libraries: say I have on library (A.js) that depends upon another one (B.js). How is this managed by Webstorm?

Comment: If A.js depends on a library created from B.js, then symbols from B.js will be used when resolving references in A.js.